# Need to escape unbalanced brackets in my perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds, parentheses, brackets

- Edit: I added  a link to a live regex tool to check the regex in action: https://regex101.com/r/906a6D/4

---

I have the following perl regular expression

```
/(\[(?>[^\[\]]+|(?1))*\])/sg
```

This works fine and matches all these strings completely

```
[a ] 

[ a] 

[a [b
]] 

[code sub t{
   my ($o,$k) = @_;
   my $c = 0;
   my $r;
   for(split //,$t){
     $r .= $_ unless(($c+($k-$o)) % $k);
     []
     $c++
   }
   $r =~ s/[^a-z]//g;
   return $r
 }]
```

However, i need to escape the brackets. If there are unbalanced ones, this won't work so i would like to escape them like this `\]` or maybe like this `{{- ] -}}`.

This should match until the last ] bracket.

```
[a \] ]
```

This should match too until the last `]`.

```
[a \]\[ ]
```

This too

```
[a \\ ]
```

I have also tried to use lookaround assertions `(?>!)`, `(?<=)` in front of  the outer brackets and with the inner ignored brackets, but then strings like this

```
[a \[ ]
```

Are completely ignored, totally unmatched, not even one character.

**I need these escaped brackets to be ignored when balancing the brackets, but still match the regexp and be captured.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
m{ ( \[ (?> [^\[\]\\]++ | \\. | (?1) )*+ \] ) }xs
```

Changes:

- added `x` flag to make it more readable
- made all quantifiers possessive because why not (otherwise I would feel uneasy about the nested quantifiers (`+` directly inside of a `*`))
- added `\` to the first character class to prevent it from being matched (like `[` and `]`, `\` has a special meaning to our regex)
- added a branch for escaped characters (`\` followed by any character is matched but otherwise ignored)

Comment: @W.Flores You removed the inner possessive quantifier. This gives me bad vibes.

Comment: changed to reflect your original answer (with the two + signs instead of one). However, this goes beyond my knowledge, i just picked the more greedy one. How this could be bad?

Comment: Yes, that looks very nice :) Covers my cases and even more! Thanks. I will put this as the accepted solution since it does what i asked. 

`(\[(?>[^\[\]\\]++|\\.|(?1))*+\])`

Comment: It should match, since what it matters is that the contents inside [ ] are captured. To this is ok to match. In fact, the idea is not to "avoid" matching but do not consider escaped brackets to do the balance.  So `[\\]` is ok. 

`[a \\ ]` should match the whole thing, as `[a \[ ]`. Both of the solutions works, except for that particular case when `[\\]` is involved

I wasn't specific about `[\\]` in particular but indeed i am happy to have both regexps to compare, since i can think of a use case for that specific use :)

Comment: @W.Flores It's not just `[\\]` in particular. The general issue is whether it should be possible to escape the escape character (and I don't see why not; it wouldn't be much of an escape character otherwise).

Comment: @melpomene Just to put your mind at ease :) The inner possessive quantifier serves no purpose because backtracking cannot occur due to the atomic nature of the outer group. This too is redundant due to the possessive nature of the group's quantifier. So you can safely use `(\[ (?: [^\[\]\\]+ | \\. | (?1) )*+ \] )` with no worries.